# How to find and delete a huge folder that was moved from Linux to Windows

Tags: windows-7, linux, disk-space

I was hoping someone could help me with this: This morning, I moved a huge folder with data (about 40GB) from my Linux partition to my Windows partition. However, I forgot to actually shut down Windows, so it was on Sleep while I was moving the file from Linux.

When I came back to Windows, not only was the folder missing, but it was actually taking up 40GB of space. I tried looking for it from Linux, but I could´t find it either.

The folder was a game so, worst scenario, I wouldn't mind having to delete it. But I would like my disk space back.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Btw, I´m using windows 7.

Edit 1:

I copied it from Linux´s normal interface. From there, I can access my Windows partition (However, I can´t access Linux from Windows). It was a normal cut and paste.

The folder in which I copied it (in Windows) is located directly on my C disk, as in: 
C:\ThisFolder

Edit 2:

I´m using an outdated version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show us the exact command you used to copy. Or did you do it from the GUI? Where exactly on your windows partition did you copy it? There are some tricks you can try but we need more details to know which directories to search through.

Comment: the folder was missing *and* taking up space?

Comment: There is nothing like "Linux's normal interface". Technically, Linux is only the *kernel*. Various utilities, like bash, cp, mv, mc, Nautilus, all (through varying levels of indirection) use the services that the kernel provides. Different distributions package various sets of utilities with varying defaults in an easier-to-install package. What you get by default with Puppylinux or SuSE is very different from what you get by default with Ubuntu or Fedora.

Comment: Yes, sorry for that, I´m not that familiar with Linux. I´m using a quite outdated version of Ubuntu, and I copied the folder to windows using its interface. No command was used, just a common cut and paste.

Comment: What do you mean by "I forgot to shut down Windows"??? What is your setup? Dual-boot? VMs?

Answer (score 0):

1. Empty Recycle Bin in Windows
2. Empty Trash in Linux,
3. Permanently delete (<kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>DEL</kbd>) the top level folder into which you were copying the game. This can be done from either Windows or Linux, but I recommend Linux, because you used it to perform original move operation.
4. Check and repair file system on that partition using windows [CHKDSK](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee872425.aspx). Use these  parameters:
   CHKDSK /X /F {Drive Letter}:
5. Unmount, then mount again the partition (or reboot the PC if this is easier)

This should resolve your problem. In fact, step 4 is the only important thing in the list above, but you might want to go through it all, just to be sure.

Next time use copy instead of move, and verify that operation completed successfully before deleting files from the source.

Comment: Some filemanagers for Linux have a setting for using copy + delete (cp+rm)  instead of move (mv), just remember this may temporarily use a lot of space.

Answer (score 0):

[TreeSizeFree](http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/) should help you locate space issues, if the number differs from what is actually used then as smc recommended, you should run a check disk to repair the File System.